# How to get attribute value from Html through axios request?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose on ajax call through Axios request I get an HTML which contains some div with some p and h tag inside it, div contain data- an attribute which holds data attribute value.

How can I pick a data attribute value in javascript? while getting the  HTML during request.

I tried using this
`let flag = $recievedHTML.$("#section").data('value');` that receivedHtml then using jquery get the value but it fails. Is it possible to get it?

```
  axios.get(url)
       .then(response => {
           console.log(response);
           const $recievedHTML = $(response.data);
           let flag = $recievedHTML.$("#section").data('value');
           console.log(flag);
       })
       .catch(error => {
           console.log(error);
       });
```

Update:

This is the $receivedHTML

```
<div class="section" data-value="true">
    <h3>Iden</h3>
    <p>Name</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post `response.data` here?

Comment: Hey @Nenad Vracar I updated and  added the ```response.data```

Comment: Try `$(response.data).data('value')`

Comment: do I don't need to use ```$("#section").data('value');``` as I have a class section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```js
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = response.data;

var value = el.querySelector(".section").getAttribute("data-value");
```

or in jQuery:

```js
var el = $('<div></div>');
el.html(response.data);

var value = $(".section",el).data("value");
```